# Making Spring Boot cron tasks configurable

Tags: spring-boot, cron, scheduled-tasks

Spring Boot allows you to create background "cron-like" tasks like so:

```
@Component
public class MyTask {
    // Every hour on the hour
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/1 1/1 * ? *")
    public void doSomething() {
        // blah whatever
    }
}
```

This makes automated integration testing a wee bit difficult! I shouldn't have to have a running integration testing just hanging for an hour, waiting to see what happens when my task runs at the top of the hour. Nor should I have to wait to run my test near the hour so that I can confirm proper behavior at the top of the hour!

**Is there a way to make these `cron` values configurable?** That way if I want to run my app in "test mode" I could schedule the `MyTask#doSomething()` method to run, say, every 30 seconds, etc.

Comment: Consider using an isolated SpringBoot test (in src/main/test) and running a test through DI and fn call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make the cron expression configurable like this

```
@Scheduled(cron ="${some.trigger}")
```

You can set this value from your `application.properties` file for dev/prod profiles. In test mode you can set this to whatever value you want using profile specific properties file, for example `application-test.properties`

Answer (score 1):

You can annotate:

```
@Profile("!test")
@Component
public class MyTask {
```

Then test application properties should contain:

```
spring:
  profiles: test
```

This would disable task execution in test mode.

I would move the code executed by the task to a separate method and test it individually without scheduling / waiting.